# How to start a eggtimer after clearInterval()?

Tags: javascript, html, timer, user-experience

A have an eggtimer which can be stopped after clicking on the button "stop". What I want is making this timer working again (from the point where it stopped) after clicking "cancel" in a confirm box. Any sugestions? Thanks for help :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="timer();">
<button onclick="exit();">stop</button>
    <p id="seconds">30</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var clock;



        function timer () {
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            clock = setInterval(function() {
                var seconds = Math.round(30 - (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000);
                if (seconds >= 0)
                    document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;
                else 
                    clearInterval(clock);



                    if (seconds==0) {window.location.href="something.com";
                    return;
                    }




            }, 1000);
        }

function exit(){

 clearInterval(clock);

var result = confirm("Are you leaving?");
if (result == true) {
window.location.href="somewhere.com";
}
else {
timer();} // <-- ????
}


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable that holds in what seconds you are ;

```
var sec  = seconds;
```

Change your function `timer` with the timer you want to start as a paramerter

```
function timer (time)
```

```js
var clock;
var sec;


function timer (time) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  clock = setInterval(function() {
    var seconds = Math.round(time - (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000);
    sec = seconds;
    if (seconds >= 0){
      document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;
    }
    else{
      clearInterval(clock);
    }
    if (seconds==0){
      window.location.href="something.com";
      return;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function exit(){
  clearInterval(clock);
  var result = confirm("Are you leaving?");
  if (result == true) {
    window.location.href="somewhere.com";
  }
  else {
  console.log(sec);
    timer(sec);} // <-- ????
}
```

```html
<body onload="timer(30);">
  <button onclick="exit();">stop</button>
  <p id="seconds">30</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example.
I moved the `seconds` variable outside the function so it persists and can be used to re-start the timer.
Also, I added an argument to the `timer()` function so the count down amount can be changed.

Note that the granularity is at the second level, so the actual count down time might eventually be longer than 30 seconds, but I believe it is acceptable in this use case.

```js
var clock;
var seconds;

function timer(wait) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  clock = setInterval(function() {
    seconds = Math.round(wait - (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000);
    if (seconds >= 0)
      document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;
    else
      clearInterval(clock);

    if (seconds == 0) {
      window.location.href = "something.com";
      return;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function exit() {

  clearInterval(clock);

  var result = confirm("Are you leaving?");
  if (result == true) {
    window.location.href = "somewhere.com";
  } else {
    timer(seconds);
  } // <-- ????
}

timer(30);
```

```html
<button onclick="exit();">stop</button>
<p id="seconds">30</p>
```